# How to stop at a whitespace in a regex pattern while moving backwards

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of string which look something like this:

```
mystring1='150 33 316LOC 300-750 22" Tet',                       
mystring2='134 ACV NOC 300-750 2-1/2" Tet'
```

I need to write a pattern that will fetch me anything before the '"' sign. In my final output the '"' should also come. I have written a code that is working for mystring2 & mystring3, but it's failing for mystring1 and mystring4.

I am attaching the code that I tried:

```
    mystring1='150 33 316LOC 300-750 22" Tet'
    attach='"'
    pattern_match = re.search('(?:\s+|$)\w*?.?\w*?.?\w*?\s?' \
    +''.join(attach.replace(' ','').split()[0]), mystring1)

    print(pattern_match.group())
```

With the above-mentioned code, I'm getting '300-750 22"' as output.

If I replace mystring1 to '150 33 316L 300-750 INC" tet', I'm getting '300-750 INC"' as an output;

My output should be 22" for '150 33 316LOC 300-750 22" tet' and
3-1/2" for '134 ACV NOC 300-750 3-1/2" tet' etc.

Comment: What is `mystring3`?

Comment: Maybe all you need is `r'\d[\d/-]*"'`?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/NEhpm5/1, but even `r'\S+"'` will work, see https://regex101.com/r/NEhpm5/2

Comment: @ScottHunter that's just another string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the problem is that 'd' only works for digits, but even if I replace it with say a '\w' it won't work for cases like'150 33 316L 300-750 2.2" tet', where it is just returning 2"

Comment: I modified it to this: r'\w*[.\w*/-]*', let me try with all the variations and will let you know if it works.

Comment: No, `r'\w*[.\w*/-]*'` is bad. Actually, `re.findall(r'[^\s"]+"', s)` below is a very good idea. Why doesn't it work for you? Again, my solution, `r'\S+"'` [still works](https://regex101.com/r/NEhpm5/3). What does `attach` hold in fact? Please clarify what `re.search('(?:\s+|$)\w*?.?\w*?.?\w*?\s?' +''.join(attach.replace(' ','').split()[0]), mystring1)` is meant to do?

Comment: Here you're hardcoding ' " ' which I can't do. It's supposed to take any characters other than words & digits or whitespaces. it will match a pattern that will vary time ti time.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions with `re` in the comments. For this simple case, one can do it without `re`:

```
lst = ['150 33 316LOC 300-750 22" Tet',
'134 ACV NOC 300-750 3-1/2" tet',
'150 33 316L 300-750 INC']

for s in lst:
    print([i for i in s.split() if i.endswith('"')])
```

Prints:

```
['22"']
['3-1/2"']
[]
```

With `re`:

```
for s in lst:
    print(re.findall(r'[^\s"]+"', s))
```

Comment: The requirement is as such that I can't take the strings in a list. It will be generated via another script and will come on to this one. But I like your approach, Thank you for showing another way.